# Detecting location services availability loss in iOS

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, nsnotificationcenter, reachability, location-services

I'm looking for this information, but I don't find it: I know you can check if location services are enabled or not, but once enabled, is it possible to listen to notifications regarding their availability?

Let's say you have them enabled for your app, and the app is getting locations, but you go into a tunnel and the device stops getting locations. Can the app be notified of that? And do location services rely on the device's reachability status?

Comment: Is it not calling failure delegate?

Comment: There is a delegate method called [locationManager:didFailWithError:] that will fire whenever the location cannot be retrieved.

Comment: -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status

Comment: @PowHu ASFAIK, that delegate method is called when location services are enabled/disabled, I'm looking for a way to know when they are available or not assuming that they are enabled...